# Create a dataframe of 13 columns and 10000 rows using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a dataframe in **spark** using **scala** of shape **13 cols and 10000 rows** with random numbers.

**I don't want to use numpy or any other library just plain old scala code.**

I have used the following code:

```
var sequence: Seq[(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)] = Nil
var i = 1
val tup  = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
while(i <= 10) {
  sequence :+= tup
  i += 1
}
val df = spark.createDataFrame(sequence)
  .toDF("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m")
df.show()
```

There are a lot of problems in this as it is using a mutable Seq and i don't think it is efficient at all but am not getting any other way of doing this.

Plus I have only used Int values but I want to have random numbers in the cols.

How do I generate this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything you've tried yet?

Comment: yeah i just edited the question with my code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scala.util.Random` to generate random numbers and for loop to generate rows.
Try the following code

```
  import scala.util.Random
  val nRows = 10000
  val seq = for (_ <- 1 to nRows)
    yield (Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows),
      Random.nextInt(nRows))

  val df = seq.toDF("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m")
  df.show()
```

Comment: **perfect!** thanks [@DragonDancing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11602896/dragondancing)